# Estoy atascado en ejercicio

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando condicionar al usuario en la variable 'productos' para que no inserte letras ni que tampoco inserte numeros que no sean 1, 2 o 3 (que son los de las opciones de la alerta), pero no logro que me salga. Pienso que es algo del flujo del programa porque las variables toman cualquier valor.
Les dejo el código:

```js
var producto = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el tipo de producto. \n 1. P1 \n 2.P2 \n 3.P3'));
  var precio, regalo, importeTotal;

  function calculaPrecio()
  {
   if (isNaN(producto))
   {
    alert('Ingresa números');
    producto = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el tipo de producto. \n 1. P1 \n 2.P2 \n 3.P3'));
   }
   else
   {
    while (producto <= 0 || producto > 3)
    {
     alert('Ingresa un número del 1 al 3');
     producto = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese el tipo de producto. \n 1. P1 \n 2.P2 \n 3.P3'));
    }
   }

   if (producto == '1') 
   {
    precio = 15;
   }
   else if (producto == '2') 
   {
    precio = 17.5;
   }
   else if (producto == '3') 
   {
    precio = 20;
   }
  }

  var unidades = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuántas unidades va a llevar?'));

  function calculaRegalo()
  {
   if (unidades < 26) 
   {
    regalo = 'un lapicero';
   }
   else if (unidades >= 26 && unidades <= 50) 
   {
    regalo = 'un cuaderno';
   }
   else
   {
    regalo = 'una agenda';
   }
  }

  function importe()
  {
   importeTotal = precio * unidades;
  }

  function mostrar()
  {
   calculaPrecio();
   calculaRegalo();
   importe();
   alert('Producto seleccionado: ' + producto + '\n Unidades: ' + unidades + ' (se lleva ' + regalo + ' de regalo) \n Importe a pagar: $' + importeTotal);
  }

  mostrar();
```

Por cierto, es un ejercicio para trabajar con funciones, quizás el cambio del flujo derive de la ultima función, donde invoco a las anteriores. La verdad no logro encontrar el error. Si me dan una mano agradecería, estoy empezando en esto!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anexo una nueva versión de tu programa esperando que sea de tu utilidad, agregué los comentarios correspondientes para que se entienda el flujo del programa. Saludos.

```js
var producto;
var unidades;
var precio;
var regalo;
var importeTotal;

function pedirProducto() {
  /* Pedir el número de la opción, repetir si no se ingresa número o el número no es 1, 2 o  3 */
  producto = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el tipo de producto. \n 1. P1 \n 2. P2 \n 3. P3 \n 4. Cancelar"));

  if (isNaN(producto) || producto < 1 || producto > 4) {
    /* Repetir Solicitud */
    pedirProducto();
  }

  if (producto === 4) {
    /* Cancelar */
    return false;;
  }

  /* Producto se estableció correctamente */
  return true;
}

function pedirUnidades() {
  /* Pedir el número de unidades, repetir si no se ingresa número */
  unidades = prompt("¿Cuantas unidades desea? (Ingrese * para cancelar todo)");

  /* Primero evaluar como texto por si el usuario quiere cancelar */
  if (unidades === '*') {
    /* Cancelar */
    return false;
  }

  /* Verificar que cualquier otro caracter ingresado sea un entero */
  if (isNaN(parseInt(unidades))) {
    /* Repetir Solicitud */
    pedirUnidades();
  }

  /* Unidades se estableció correctamente */
  return true;
}


function calculaPrecio() {
  /* Producto es de tipo int no es necesario las comillas */
  if (producto === 1) {
    precio = 15;
  }
  else if (producto === 2) {
    precio = 17.5;
  }
  else if (producto === 3) {
    precio = 20;
  }
}

function calculaRegalo() {
  /* Determinar el regalo */
  if (unidades < 26) {
    regalo = "Un lapicero";
  }
  else if (unidades >= 26 && unidades <= 50) {
    regalo = "Un cuaderno";
  }
  else {
    regalo = "Una agenda";
  }
}

function calculaImporte() {
  /* Calcular el importa */
  importeTotal = precio * unidades;
}

function mostrarResultado() {
  alert("Producto seleccionado: " + producto + "\nUnidades: " + unidades + " (se lleva " + regalo + " de regalo) \nImporte a pagar: $" + importeTotal);
}

/* Auto ejecutar función */
(function mostrar() {
  /* Si no se declara bien la variable producto es que se canceló la operación */
  if (!pedirProducto()) {
    /* Programa terminado */
    alert("¡Hasta luego!");
    /* Cancelar ejecución del resto de esta función */
    return;
  }

  /* Si no se declara bien la variable unidades es que se canceló la operación */
  if (!pedirUnidades()) {
    /* Programa terminado */
    alert("¡Hasta luego!");
    /* Cancelar ejecución del resto de esta función */
    return;
  }

  /* En este punto ambas variables se declararon correctamente */
  calculaPrecio();
  calculaRegalo();
  calculaImporte();
  mostrarResultado();
})();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :). Se podría decir que el problema central estaba en la organización del flujo del programa?

Comment: Así es, el código original no estaba organizado de la mejor manera, recuerda que uno de los propósitos de usar funciones es evitar repetir fragmentos de código, esto a su vez permite que tengamos mejor control del programa en general.